# Fetching json into applicaiton and real time updation

Tags: android, json

Fetch data from a Web API(contains `JSON database`) and display it in the form of tables and simultaneously when the data in that API change. The app should also show the same change in the tables(*real-time updates*) as in weather reports, share market rates etc.

Comment: You can use FireBase to push data or you use timer pull request to server ask data change. If changed, you get data.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why 
it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time 
to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, 
and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! 
See also: [ask]

Comment: Okay,thank u for the help.